# Ruby PKCS7 fails to verify when data contains line breaks

Tags: ruby, openssl

I find that when I call `OpenSSL::PKCS7#verify`, if the data to be verified contains line breaks, then `verify` returns false:

```rb
require 'openssl'

def test(data)
  store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
  signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(@cert, @key, data).to_der
  pkcs7 = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(signed)
  valid = pkcs7.verify(pkcs7.certificates, store, data, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
end

@key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
@cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
@cert.serial = 0
@cert.public_key = @key.public_key
@cert.not_before = Time.now
@cert.not_after = Time.now + 2**12
@cert.sign @key, OpenSSL::Digest.new('SHA256')

test("foo")   # => true
test("foo\n") # => false
```

(I even have the `NOVERIFY` flag in the function call!)

Why does the presence of a line break change the behaviour? It has this effect regardless of where I put the line break in the data string. How can I verify a signature if the input string contains a line break?

*This is Ruby 2.6.8p205.*

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @anothermh, I've updated the code example to be a complete minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you. After digging through ruby/openssl and openssl/openssl I can confidently say I'm stumped. As a workaround, encode your data in some manner before signing, e.g., `test(Base64.strict_encode64("foo\n")) => true` or `test("foo\n".bytes.map { |d| d.to_s(2) }.map{ |b| b.rjust(8, '0') }.join) => true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching this seems to be expected behavior.
It's converting LF to CRLF before signing:

```
test("foo")     # => true
test("foo\n")   # => false
test("foo\r\n") # => true
```

To fix you need to use the `BINARY` flag:

```
signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(@cert, @key, data, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY).to_der
```

Now:

```
test("foo")     # => true
test("foo\n")   # => true
test("foo\r\n") # => true
```

Sources for this info:

> **Normally the supplied content is translated into MIME canonical format (as required by the S/MIME specifications). If PKCS7_BINARY is set no translation occurs**. This option should be used if the supplied data is in binary format otherwise the translation will corrupt it.

[1] https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/PKCS7_sign.html
[2] https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/9336
[3] https://opensource.apple.com/source/ruby/ruby-75/ruby/test/openssl/test_pkcs7.rb

Comment: Great find, gotta love those [undocumented flags](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/master/ext/openssl/ossl_pkcs7.c#L1078). I tried searching for a binary solution but kept being directed to cms which isn't supported in Ruby OpenSSL.